# Unassigned variable error

Tags: c#, unassigned-variable

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        public delegate void mydel(int z);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();

            Random r = new Random();
            int k = r.Next(99);

            mydel f;

            if (k > 50)
            {
                f = new mydel(p.high);
            }

            if (k < 50)
            {
                f = new mydel(p.low);
            }

            //f(k) is underlined and Use of unassigned local variable 'f'     
            f(k);
        }

        //methods
        public void high(int m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}>50", m);
        }

        public void low(int n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}<50", n);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected f(k) to work because I gave parameter to delegate. Why am I getting this error? (Use of unassigned local variable 'f' on f(k) portion)

Comment: add additional else. `if(k>50){...} else if(k<50){...} else {...}` in case that `k==50`

Comment: What if `k == 50`?  Then `f` will not be assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `null`

```
mydel f = null
```

Or put else between conditions. Because, when `k == 50` f is not initialized:

```
    mydel f;

    if (k > 50)
    {
        f = new mydel(p.high);
    }
    else
    {
        f = new mydel(p.low);
    }
```

Comment: Does compiler check whether I covered all possibilities in if else blocks or not in compile time?

Comment: @Lyrk it checks that variable is initialized. it's equal to `mydel f = k > 50 ? new mydel(p.high) : new mydel(p.low);` so variable is assigned

Answer (score 2):

if `k > 50` then f is some delegate, if `k < 50` - too. What if `k == 50`? `f` is not specified (even it is not null) in that case - so you can't use it.

Quick fix:

```
mydel f = null;
```

But you will get `NullReferenceException` when `k == 50`;
You can also add additional `if` for case when `k == 50`;